# php, key check on NULL variable gets set, how to?

Tags: php, arrays, null, isset

here is my example:

```
$data = null;

var_dump($data); // returns null

is($data['test']);

var_dump($data); // returns array (size=1)
                 //            'test' => null

function is(&$var, $default = null)
{
    return isset($var) ? $var : $default;
}
```

notice that after I run `is($data['test'])`,  `$data` becomes `$data['test'] = null`

any ideas why this behavior?

I am looking to get `null`. I am running php 7

edit: it's the `&` symbol, just not sure why would yield that result

Comment: Note that it works if you don't pass first argument by reference:       `function is($var, $default = null)`

Comment: @FredB yeah, it does, but sometimes I get notices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass a variable with a non existing key to a function (even with reference) since the value will be passed to the function.

If we have `$data` and in the next line if we do `$data['test']`, the `$data` variable will be updated to an array.

So in your case, when you use `is($data['test']);`, it updates the variable.

Then it goes to the function, and checks `isset($var)`. It is already set since the variable is updated already. So the `isset` gets a `true` return. That return will contain the updated variable which is `$data['test']`.

I think the solution from @Fred B will work in this case.

Comment: I see, `$data['test']` gets evaluated first

Answer (score 0):

try using array_key_exists() and return null if key not found.

Answer (score 0):

This solution seems to work, though less elegant:

```
is($data, 'test');

var_dump($data); // returns array (size=1)
                 //            'test' => null

function is($var, $key, $default = null)
{
    return isset($var[$key]) ? $var[$key] : $default;
}
```

Comment: yeah, I understand how to check if a key or variable exists, there are many ways, I was wondering about that `&` symbol in particular